# Conceptualizing time series data of fluctuating sizes of particle aggregates

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, simulations, stochastic-processes

I am working with simulation data (a time series of positions) of aggregating particles. I want to look at the overall distribution of aggregate size.

A colleague calculated the number of aggregates of the particles, which he averaged over time. These aggregates have different sizes. My understanding is that this amounts essentially to many time series -- one for each size of aggregate. Then, he calculated the histogram of counts vs. size of aggregate. All I have is the histogram, but following my reading, I think I should actually be using the time series data in verifying the distribution, and so on. However, it seems that typically one time series is analyzed to get a distribution, but that is not the case here. Can somebody help clear up my thinking on this? I wonder if this is a basic problem in dealing with time series data that I just am not aware of.

(I apologize if I'm wording this in a way that isn't clear, hence the vague title. I'm trying to wrap my head around this problem and formalize it, as much as possible.)

Comment: The core of your question is quite difficult to follow! I would try to: 1) define properly your observables (what is exactly an aggregate in your simulation, what are the variables in your time series,...). 2) Identify and ask clear questions,  is difficult to evaluate your general thoughts, breaking them into simpler doubts will make them more accessible. Finding a proper way to state your problem could be of great help to find the solution on your own also ;).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, but I will attempt to answer my best interpretation of your question, which is "how do I find the distribution of aggregate size, for each timestep".

Simply track the size of each aggregate at each time step, and plot the distributions for a given timestep. To avoid a using a histrogram directly in order to estimate maximum likelyhood, consider using something like a Savitzky-golay filter on your histrogram. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter

This will smooth your data and make for better results. Of course another way to smooth your data is just make your system bigger.

One more note: you probably need to run the simulation more than once, using different initial conditions if you want to characterize its properties in general.

Comment: "Simply track the size of each aggregate at each time step" - I don't think that will work because an aggregate consists of many particles that might change dramatically over time. An aggregate might totally dissolve into the individual particles constituting it, etc.